# Printing a tree with branches recursively

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to print a tree recursively in Python. For some reason, the indentation isn't working (perhaps I'm too tired at this point to see an obvious flaw). Here's the structure / class definitions that I'm working with:

```
class Tree(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.branches = []

class Branch(object):
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.label = value
    self.node = None
```

As you see, each tree has Branches, which have a label and point to another Tree (that's the `node` value you see there). Here's how I'm trying to print out the tree:

```
  def __str__(self):
    return self.tree_string(0)

  def tree_string(self, indent):
    indentation = indent * " "
    result = indentation + str(self.data) + "\n";
    for branch in self.branches:
      result += indentation + branch.label + ": \n" + branch.node.tree_string(indent + 2)
    return result
```

This is giving me:

```
4
Somewhat: 
  Yes
Fuller: 
  3
Correct: 
  8
Caribbean: 
  2
Wrong: 
  Wrong
Correct: 
  Correct

Italian: 
  Wrong
Burger: 
  Correct

Wrong: 
  Wrong

Nothing: 
  Wrong
```

When it should be giving me something like

```
4
Somewhat: 
  Correct
Fuller: 
  3
  Correct: 
    8
    Caribbean: 
      2
      Wrong: 
        Wrong
      Correct: 
        Correct
    Italian: 
      Wrong
    Burger: 
     Correct
  Wrong: 
    Wrong
Nothing: 
  Wrong
```

What's causing my code to have those extra newlines and not have the proper indents?

**Update**

Pretty sure the data is ok. Here's a modified version that shows it's ok:

```
  def tree_string(self, indent):
    indentation = indent * " "
    result = str(self.data);
    if len(self.branches) > 0:
      result += "["
      for branch in self.branches:
        result += branch.label + ":" + branch.node.tree_string(indent + 2) + " "
      result += "]"
    return result
```

..which gives the output

`4[Somewhat:Correct Fuller:3[Correct:8[Caribbean:2[No:No Correct:Correct ] Italian:Wrong Burger:Correct ] Wrong:Wrong ] Nothing:Wrong ]`

However, the indent values are for some reason always 0 or 2.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input data?

Comment: Kinda hard to do that since I can't print the tree ;). But if you mean the algorithm that's used to generate this, no not really... It's essentially ID3 that is trying to classify things as 'correct' or 'wrong'

Comment: on the third line of the second part are you multiplying the string

Comment: Code looks like it should work.  Next place I'd look would be the formation of the tree. @aaronman, that's proper syntax for duplicated characters.

Comment: @aaronman, It is Python syntax for concatenating a string to itself: `>>> "-"*7` `'-------'`

Comment: Yeah, code looks fine to me too. Sure it's not a data issue?

Comment: Didn't know that, interesting

Comment: @garromark 99% sure it's not the formation of the tree, and that it's the whitespaces or something. I made a variation of the above that shows that the structure should be good... i'll post in a few seconds

Comment: @varatis Maybe try printing the "indent" value along with the self.data value to show what level it's trying to print?  Can you show us the output with that printed?

Comment: @garromark I think what I just printed shows that the structure is ok (the children are nested correctly). However, the indents are all screwed up -- they aren't the values they're supposed to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it should work to me:

```
class Tree(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.branches = []
  def __str__(self):
    return self.tree_string(0)

  def tree_string(self, indent):
    indentation = indent * " "
    result = indentation + str(self.data) + "\n";
    for branch in self.branches:
      result += indentation + branch.label + ": \n" + branch.node.tree_string(indent + 2)
    return result

class Branch(object):
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.label = value
    self.node = None

tree = Tree(4)
b1 = Branch('Somewhat')
b1.node = Tree('Yes')
b2 = Branch('Fuller')
b2.node = Tree(3)
tree.branches = [b1, b2]
b3 = Branch('Correct')
b3.node = Tree(8)
b2.node.branches = [b3]
print(tree)
```

yields

```
4
Somewhat: 
  Yes
Fuller: 
  3
  Correct: 
    8
```

Comment: Yep. There must be something weird going on with the data, because it appears to have the correct structure in terms of how its children are laid out, so I'll just look into that further.